# How can I replace left CSS attribute (set in .css file) with right CSS attribute dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment

I am working with a pre-existing javascript plugin (a slider) that aligns one of it's internal elements (navigation icons) with "left:50px". Under very specific circumstances, I want to align this to the right, using "right:50px" instead. The problem is that when I add "right:50px" to it inline, the right property is still over-ruled by the pre-existing "left:50px" property that is set in the plugin's .css file. I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to remove the left property, or to overwrite it with some other value, such as "left:none".

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
left: auto;
```

Along with setting the `right` property. It's not that your `right` declaration is being ignored, rather it will be applied at the same time as the existing `left`.

Comment: I'm having a laugh at myself now for asking something that should have been so obvious. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: No worries - it's always the little things. I still find it confusing the various ways you need to reset certain CSS properties (none/auto/sometimes it's impossible).